# gradlew Ошибка: Failed to install the following SDK components

Tags: android-sdk, gradle, android-gradle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке вывести tasks, gradlew выводит ошибку. Когда пытался устранить с помощью sdkmanager, вывело новую ошибку об эмуляторе. Как это связано и как можно устранить без android studio?
Использую терминал от nethunter'а на андроид, так что можно проводить параллели с linux. К компьютеру нету доступа.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять версию `Gradle`. Это `7.0`? Проверьте на `7.0.1` или `6.7.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена путём установки вручную с https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-build-tools.html?m=1
:)